# To use Symbols in limits of Definite integral

Tags: numpy, scipy, physics, sympy

I want to use the limits (Ef-e*V) and Ef as lower and upper limits in my Definite integral. where Ef is given 10 electron volts , e is the electronic charge and I want the ans in terms of V 
How would i DO THAT????
PLEASE HELP

````
    from scipy.integrate import quad
    import sympy as sp
    import math

    e = 1.6 * (10 ** -19)
    L = 10 ** -9
    h = 6.626 * (10 ** -34)
    h_cut = 1.05 * (10 ** -34)
    m = 9.11 * (10 ** -31)
    V0 = 4.0*e  # in J
    EF = 10.0*e  # in J
    E = sp.Symbol('E')
    V = sp.Symbol('V')



    def f(E):
        j = (4 * E * (V0 - E)) / (4 * E * (V0 - E) + V0 ** 2 * ((2 * m * (V0 - E)) * ((L / h_cut) ** 2)))
        return j


    i, err = quad(f, EF - e * V, EF)
    print('i= ', i)
    I = (2 * e * i) / h
    print(I)
    ```
THE error is as follows:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Subham/Desktop/Integration/integration.py", line 22, in <module>
    i, err = quad(f, EF - e * V, EF)
  File "C:\Users\Subham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 337, in quad
    flip, a, b = b < a, min(a, b), max(a, b)
  File "C:\Users\Subham\Desktop\Integration\venv\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\relational.py", line 304, in __nonzero__
    raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of Relational")
TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
````

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55793439/cannot-determine-truth-value-of-relational.  Different `f` function, same error.  All inputs to `quad` must be numeric, including the boundaries.

Comment: @hpaulj i read that but no solution is there also

Comment: Have you tried to use `sympy.integrate`?

Comment: Yesh.  But error shows , saying , invalid limits

Comment: Yes, I got that error too.

Comment: Can you share any other way of doing it.. ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using SymPy, you could do the integral there. It works best if you work with Rational numbers, however, so we do this

```
>>> gx = nsimplify(f(x), rational=True)
```

Then compute the integral

```
>>> i = integrate(gx, (x,EF-e*V,EF))
```

And display it at whatever precision you desire. Here is the result to 2 sigfigs on each number:

```
>>> nfloat(i, 2)
1.6e-19*V + 1.7e-17*log(1.9e-17 - 1.6e-19*V) + 6.5e-16
```